# How to get sum up rows of a column by grouping another column?

Tags: r, dataframe

My DF has two columns One is state names and another one is No of event happened.
This Data had more columns and now I want to sum up all the no of events happened by state. how can I do that?

Comment: have a look at `?aggregate`

Answer (score 0):

How about using `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  summarize(total_event = sum(event))
```

Here I have supposed your data is in `DF` data frame and it has columns names `state` and `event`.

Comment: It didn't help me. I got help from below code.                    
                                                                                          
aggregate(df$Total, by=list(Category=df$State), FUN=sum)

Comment: That is very fine, it might help you in future when you will have to do more sophisticated summaries and groupings. `data.table` and `dplyr` are very good alternatives.